# EXCEL: How to extract a subarray from a column based on the values of another column?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm working with a table that contains information about categories of products and oracle tables related with such products. Just like this:

[image: Table with info of different products]

I was trying to figure out how to extract in another location the tables used by each product using a dropdown list, for example:

If any of the product is selected from the dropdown list the tables marked by an X in the previous table must be shown as in the red square.
[image: Expected result]

I was trying using INDEX, XLOOKUP, FILTER and combination of them unsuccessfully

Somebody can help me to figure out how to obtain the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FILTER will do this, what was the formula you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using INDEX/MATCH in the FILTER:

```
=FILTER(Table1[TABLE],INDEX(Table1[#Data],0,MATCH(H2,Table1[#Headers],0))="x")
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was doing but I was missing the match!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this formula - I named the table `data`

```vb
=LET(getColumn,FILTER(data,data[#Headers]=H3),
     FILTER(data[Table],getColumn="x"))
```